# How to create a new user that can login to SSH and execute a set of commands

Tags: linux, ssh, shell

I'm trying to setup new users for a particular directory but I want them to be able to see just one directory (and subfolders).

For example:

I have a server that has the following directories:

```
apache-user www-data /var/sites/mercury.solar-domain.com
apache-user www-data /var/sites/venus.solar-domain.com
apache-user www-data /var/sites/earth.solar-domain.com
apache-user www-data /var/sites/mars.solar-domain.com
apache-user www-data /var/sites/jupiter.solar-domain.com
apache-user www-data /var/sites/saturn.solar-domain.com
apache-user www-data /var/sites/uranos.solar-domain.com
apache-user www-data /var/sites/neptune.solar-domain.com
```

I want to add a new user: `jupiter` that could:

- Login to the server through ssh
- Is able to run via ssh `scp`, `php`, `mysql`, `rsync` (e.g.: `$ mysql -u jupiter -p`)
- The only visible directory for the user is: /var/sites/jupiter.solar-domain.com
- When the user logs in (through ssh) he can not go to another directory of the system (/usr, /root, /var/log, etc...)

I have checkout `chroot` and `restricted shell` but I don't think that their are the proper tool for me (or maybe I don't know how to configure them).

With chroot the problem is that I cannot change the user:group of the directory, for example: `apache-user www-data /var/sites/jupiter.solar-domain.com` will have to stay the same, I can add `jupiter` to the `www-data` group but I can not change the user:group of the folder.

With restricted shell looks like the user will only able to use a restricted set of commands like scp, sftp, rsync, cvs and rdist, but I want them to be able to use mysql and php.

Thank you very much for your guidance on how to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try your luck with [ACL](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-manage-acls-on-linux).

You could have your user's home on `/var/sites/jupiter.solar-domain.com`.

Then set ACL's to also give the right to `apache-user` and `www-data` to access those folders.

Here's what you need to do:

1. Set your filesystem to use ACLs
2. Create your user `jupiter` with the home directory `/var/sites/jupiter.solar-domain.com`
3. Restrict his environment (check [this Redhat procedure](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/65822)) (Restricted shell is something you need, and you can add the commands `mysql` and `php` in the **PATH**). Beware that in SSH, you need to set the PATH in .bashrc as well.
4. Set your directory to have apache-user with the rights : `setfacl -d -m u:apache-user:rw jupiter.solar-domain.com`
5. Also set the rights for the group `www-data`.